# Fix tooltip to selection, don't move when scrolling

Tags: javascript, popper.js

I use popper.js to attach a tooltip to a text selection.

```js
function generateGetBoundingClientRect(rangeRect) {
    return () => ({
        width: rangeRect.width,
        height: rangeRect.height,
        top: rangeRect.top,
        right: rangeRect.right,
        bottom: rangeRect.bottom,
        left: rangeRect.left,
    });
}

const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)

const positionElement = {
    getBoundingClientRect: this.generateGetBoundingClientRect(range.getBoundingClientRect()),
    };

const instance = createPopper(positionElement, menu, {placement: 'top'});
```

Unfortunately, the so-created menu is not fixed to the selection but scrolls with the viewport. As this is achieved by `translate()`, I assume there is an option in popper.js to turn that of?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was fairly obvious and – to the credit of the popper.js team – in the [documentation](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/event-listeners/).

The solution is to turn of listening to scroll events, which can be achieved by passing the `eventListener` modifier and set `scroll:false`. In code:

```
const instance = createPopper(positionElement, menu, {
            placement: 'top',
            modifiers: [
                {
                    name: 'eventListeners',
                    options: {scroll: false}
                }
            ],
        });
```